# Use GUI Emacs on OS X when opening files with emacsclient

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm trying to setup Emacs (which I installed via `brew install emacs --cocoa`) in a way that I can use it the in following way:

1. `emacsclient file.txt` creates a new GUI Frame if there is none already
2. `emacsclient file2.txt` replaces the contents of the existing frame if there is one
3. `emacsclient` should always return immediately and not block the shell it has been called from
4. At any given point in time there should basically be one Emacs window and one `emacs --daemon` process

As I said I installed Emacs via homebrew. To have a daemon starting when I log in I added `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.gnu.emacs.plist` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.gnu.emacs</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacs</string>
      <string>--daemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I confirmed that this starts the process. So far I tried various variants to call emacsclient:

1. `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient file.txt` this opens emacs in my terminal
2. `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient -c file.txt` this opens up a new Emacs GUI frame (good!) but it somehow does not have the same font-size/typeface settings. Also when I close that frame and open another file with `emacsclient -c` the Emacs process seems to crash.
3. `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/bin/emacsclient -n file.txt` just exits right away

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I've found a lot of tutorials on this but many weren't clear if the objective is to get a daemon working just for terminal usage of emacs etc.

I'd be very interested to hear how you use Emacs on OS X, especially how you setup an Emacs daemon and how/if you are using the GUI variant.

Answer (score 6):

As it happens so often I found a solution while writing this. Putting the following into my `init.el` allowed me to open files in the existing GUI frame.

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

I assume that this works because the server process is bound to the GUI instance of Emacs but I'm still very open to someone else enlightening me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as 2019 goes, this answer really works for me. This is my configuration for using emacsclient and emacs daemon in macos Mojave with [emacs-mac v.26.2](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport):

1) First, I put this line in my init file:

```
(server-start)
```

As [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) and Martin explain, this line is necessary for link the GUI Emacs to the server it creates.

2) Then, I set the Emacs GUI to start at the beginning of my mac session (there is no magic here, It is set as any other application).

3) Finally, I create a [shortcut](https://www.howtogeek.com/286332/how-to-run-any-mac-terminal-command-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) for this terminal command using automator:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-26.2-z-mac-7.6/bin/emacsclient -c -a ""
```

and bound it to any keybinding of my preference (I set mine to shift + super + e) using the keyboard menu of my mac preferences.

After this, you are set to go. Emacs GUI will start when the session begins and with just a fast shortcut it will quickly open an emacsclient frame.

PD: Do NOT close the emacs GUI, It is essential to keep it running as emacsclient needs it to create a new graphical frame. See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options).

Answer (score 0):

By gathering information from other threads, I've finally come up with a very simple solution.

Create a shell script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if ps -e | grep '[E]macs.app' > /dev/null; then
    emacsclient -n "$@"
else
    open -a "Emacs" --args --chdir $PWD "$@"
fi
# The --chdir argument is necessary to pass relative paths to Emacs.
```

and call it `emacs` and put it in a place your PATH includes.

Then, you simply type

```sh
$ emacs fileyouwanttoopen
```

If the GUI emacs isn't running, the script launches it.  If it is running, the script asks it to handle the file.